# Kendo grid not displaying Clolumns data that are not include in client templete row

Tags: kendo-grid

My Isuue is,I have added kendo grid and bounded with data getting from a particular class. Then, I appended with one more column includes icons by using client row templete.
corresponding data is not displaying after I appended with one more column(client row templete.before its working absolutely fine). I need to show data in all columns.

I tried to include  but failed.
My Code is-
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid
            (Model.Services)

```
        .Name("SummaryGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Service_Name).Title("Service Name");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Service_Type).Title("Service Type");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Service_Resource).Title("Resource");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Region).Title("Region");
            columns.Bound(c => c.TotalQuantity).Title("Quantity");
            columns.Bound(c => c.UnitOfMeasure).Title("Unit of Measure");
            columns.Bound(c => c.TotalCost).Title("Total Cost($)");
            columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Title("Actions");


        })
        .ClientRowTemplate(

                  " <td >" +
                       "<a href='javascript:void(0);' title='Edit' class='clsEditService'>  <span class='icon-E70F blackIcon'></span></a>" + " </a>"+
                       "<a href='javascript:void(0);' title='Delete' class='clsDeleteService'>"+
                        "<span class='icon-E74D blackIcon'></span>"+" </a>"+

                  " </td>"    

        )
```

Expected grid to show all columns  corresponding data at the end edit and delete icons as well(I am not looking for default edit and delete functionalities from kendo)

Answer (score 0):

A `ClientRowTemplate` adds a row below your grid row. If you want a column for your edit/delete, try something like this:

```
columns.Template(e => {}).Title("Actions")
    .ClientTemplate("@<a title='Edit' class='clsEditService'><span class='k-grid-edit icon-E70F blackIcon'></span></a>  " +
                    "<a title='Delete' class='clsDeleteService'><span class='k-grid-delete icon-E74D blackIcon'></span></a>");
```

Note that if you add the classes `k-grid-edit` and `k-grid-delete` this will tell kendo to run your update and delete Ajax actions automatically, otherwise set your own events accordingly.